# how to get the value of an option in select menu onChange using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm trying to implement clone select menu using the [ScrollectBox](https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox) plugin:

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/index.html

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/js/ScrollectBox/jquery.scrollectbox.js

but I'm unable to get the option value of the select menu. It returns the option text instead.

How to get the value (but not text) of an option in the following select menu `onChange` using jQuery call function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
   $(".selection").scrollectBox({
    preset: 'dropdown',
    numVisibleOptions: 4,
    scrollInterval: 150, 
    scrollOn: 'hover'
    });
});
</script>
```

---

```
    <select onchange="function(this);" id="selector" class="selection" >
    <option value="" selected="Select Topic">Select Topic</option> 
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Drink">Drink</option>
    </select>
```

---

***Doesn't work***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
   var selectEvent = function($el){
someFunction($(this).val());
return false;
};
   $(".selection").scrollectBox({
    preset: 'dropdown',
    numVisibleOptions: 4,
    onSelectEvent: selectEvent,
    scrollInterval: 150, 
    scrollOn: 'hover'
    });
});
</script>
```

it returns `[object Object]`

***Doesn't work***

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $(".selection").scrollectBox({
        preset: 'dropdown',
        numVisibleOptions: 4,
        scrollInterval: 150, 
        scrollOn: 'hover',
        onSelectEvent: function (item, event) {
           alert(item).val();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

it returns `[object Object]`

Answer (score 4):

According to the source code for [ScrollectBox](https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/js/ScrollectBox/jquery.scrollectbox.js), you must use the `onSelectEvent` property, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $(".selection").scrollectBox({
        preset: 'dropdown',
        numVisibleOptions: 4,
        scrollInterval: 150, 
        scrollOn: 'hover',
        onSelectEvent: function (item, event) {
           alert(item.val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: how can i call the function within the select menu class `.selection` but not the id `#selector` ? thanks,

Comment: @SilentPond Just change `#selector` with `.selector`

Comment: thanks @mattytommo but the code doesn't work together with `$(".selection").scrollectBox({`

Comment: @SilentPond Check my update, just read the `Scrollectbox` source code.

Comment: @mattytommo thanks for edited code. i tried your code cleanly & independently with select menu unfortunately it can't retrieve the option value again. instead it's retrieving the option text. besides i'm already using `onSelectEvent:` . please check my edited question. how can i call the option value using your code with the existing code i edited.

Comment: @SilentPond Change `someFunction(this)` to be `someFunction($(this).val());`

Comment: @mattytommo i did that but i'm unable to change the option value even this time as the option value is halted to the url something like `test.com/index.html#` something must be wrong. please check the reedited question. i check the code with `ie` console. the consle gives error `nodeName is null or not an object` generated in line no.2317 of `jquery-1.7.1.js`which is as following: `hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ];`
. thanks,

Comment: @mattytommo i tried your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15546743/1799764 after changing the `onSelectEvent` from null to true in `https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/js/ScrollectBox/jquery.scrollectbox.js` now i get the alert `[object Object]` whenever i try to change the option. any idea shall be well appreciated. thanks,

Comment: @SilentPond What are you trying to alert?

Comment: @mattytommo i want to call / get the option values onchange and pass these on to the function `someFunction(this);` so that this function can handle these values for accomplishing it's task. i've created two anonymous demo links for your convenience. please look at my edited question for these links. thanks,

Comment: @SilentPond Ah, in your second example there's a JS error (I had my code wrong). Change `alert(item).val();` to be `alert(item.val());`

Comment: @mattytommo  i have updated the code in clone  select menu url. it still can't get and pass the value. thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the selected option via: `$("#selector option:selected")`

```
$("#selector").change(function() {
   var selectedValue = $("#selector option:selected").val();
   alert('Selected value ' + selectedValue);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Y7byM/1/

**Edit**:

From your comments you can change `#selector` to `.selector`:

```
$(".selection").change(function() {
   var selectedValue = $(".selector option:selected").val();
   alert('Selected value ' + selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: Is it the old age that made you miss that the OP wants the `value` and not the `text`? ;)

Comment: @Darren Davies, `mattytommo` is correct. it's about the option value but not the option text. but up vote for the comment though i know you weren't after that. thanks,

Comment: @SilentPond - I updated my answer to use `val` and I have included a fiddle to show it working.

Comment: thanks @Darren Davies  but can't i get value calling the function within existing class `.selection` thanks,

Comment: @SilentPond - the code should work fine.  What happens when you run it?

Comment: hi @Darren Davies yes, your edited code works fine independently but when i use your code with the existing call function of my post it returns a url like `test.com/index.html#` `onchange` of options caused by `line no.133` of `https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/js/ScrollectBox/jquery.scrollectbox.js`. that's why i asked how can i call the value with existing class call function `$(".selection").scrollectBox({` i posted but not as a separate call function? thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Tried this ?

```
$('#selector').change(function() {
           // assign the value to a variable, so you can test to see if it is working.
            var selectVal = $('#selector :selected').val();
            alert(selectVal);
        });
```

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ: this is working fine. But, when it is loaded for the first time, some option is displayed in dropdown select. In that time, this alert won't come right? Only when you changing the option, the option value is assigning to the variable. In that case, how can I get the option value onload

Answer (score 0):

My "select" is provided via an AJAX call, and I could not get the calling program to work with the .change method.

The table (not declared until an AJAX call is made) is

```
<select id="provincePick">
<option value="0" >Choose a province:</option>
<option value="AB">Alberta</option>
<option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
<option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
<option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
<option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
<option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
<option value="ON">Ontario</option>
<option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
<option value="QC">Quebec</option>
<option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
<option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
<option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
<option value="YT">Yukon</option>
```

The jQuery code I needed in the calling program was

```
    $("body").on("change", "#provincePick", function(e)
    {
        alert( this.value );
    });
```

Now the alert works.