# Dropdown Menu: onChange, find select id of option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take for example, I have the following structure:

```
<select id = 'omg' onchange= 'select(this.value)'>
    <option>'wow'</option>
    <option>'pls'</option>
    <option>'werk'</option>
</select>
```

Upon selecting an option, the select function whatever it may look like will output the selected value of the option, that being, 'wow', 'pls', 'werk'.

I'm currently stuck trying to select the id of the dropdown menu. An example of my desired result would be to select any of the 3 options, and then to have the onchange function output being 'omg'.

---

My current idea is to have

```
onchange = 'select(this.value, this)'
```

where the onchange function itself looks something like this:

```
function select(value, element) {
    var ele = element ; //part where I'm stuck on (I select entire object, but now what?)
    //code for what I want to do with value but that's irrelevant to question
}
```

Comment: Do you want the value of the selected option or the text?

Comment: I want the select to output the "select id" of the entire <select>. Not id of specific options, as they obviously they don't exist.

Comment: @Xenyal Musa has answered your question in the first comment in this thread. More interesting is, what you're going to do with that `id`, since you've a reference to the actual element already.

Comment: I'm beginner to Js so finding the id was 90% of the issue for me. What comes after, I won't need to ask on StackOverflow haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this?

```
<select id = "omg" onchange="select(this.value)">
<option value="0">'wow'</option>
<option value="1">'pls'</option>
<option value="2">'werk'</option>
</select>
```

EDITED: based on comments - this is optional approach since there is a default method to obtain text in case value attribute is not declared.

Comment: You misunderstood my question; the 2nd paragraph was for context. The last paragraph outlines my problem.

Comment: Actually it's not necessary, `select.value` is automatically set to `option.text`, if the selected option didn't have `value` attribute.

Comment: Learned something new, @Teemu.  Thank you.  Xenyal -I see your problem issue and reviewing it.  But on the top of the head, would you consider trying jQuery in this?  I found it to be sexy easy. ;)

Comment: Like I mentioned about jQuery - I found similar method that you are seeking, hopefully it is the one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546670/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-option-in-select-menu-onchange-using-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery you can also do this:

Based on this comment above: "*I want the select to output the "select id" of the entire . Not id of specific options, as they obviously they don't exist.*"

```
   $(document).on('ready',function(){
      $("#omg").on('change',function(e){ console.log($(this).attr('id'), " returns = ", $(this).val() );  });     
    });
```

Comment: Would this not return the value of the selected option, instead of the id of the <select>?